# What is the relationship between event loop and Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, theory, event-loop

I am curious about the relationship between Event Loop and Promise.
The demo exposes the question. I expected the `p1 fulfilled` appear in the middle, <strike>since they queue a task to the same task queue and are executed one by one.</strike>

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(1)
})
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("will be executed at the top of the next Event Loop")
},0)
p1.then(function(value){
  console.log("p1 fulfilled")
})
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("will be executed at the bottom of the next Event Loop")
},0)
```

The console result is:

```
p1 fulfilled
will be executed at the top of the next Event Loop
will be executed at the bottom of the next Event Loop
```

[The visualized effect](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=dmFyIHAxID0gbmV3IFByb21pc2UoZnVuY3Rpb24ocmVzb2x2ZSwgcmVqZWN0KXsKICAgIHJlc29sdmUoMSkKfSk7CnNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24oKXsKICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygid2lsbCBiZSBleGVjdXRlZCBhdCB0aGUgdG9wIG9mIHRoZSBuZXh0IEV2ZW50IExvb3AiKQp9LDApCnAxLnRoZW4oZnVuY3Rpb24odmFsdWUpewogIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCJwMSBmdWxmaWxsZWQiKQp9KQpzZXRUaW1lb3V0KGZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7CiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIndpbGwgYmUgZXhlY3V0ZWQgYXQgdGhlIGJvdHRvbSBvZiB0aGUgbmV4dCBFdmVudCBMb29wIikKfSwwKQ%3D%3D!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D) shows the `promise.then`'s callback didn't go to the task queue of the Event Loop. It's right?

【NOTE: The question is not the same as [Promise vs setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752620/promise-vs-settimeout), since it focus more on the relationship between Event Loop and Promise】

Comment: You can imagine a second task queue that is processed at the end of the current [tick](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick) i.e. before anything in the normal task queue.

Comment: `setTimeout` also has a minimum delay.

Comment: _"I expected the `p1 fulfilled` appear in the middle."_ Why do you expect that result?

Comment: @torazaburo it's not a duplicate. The question `Promise vs setTimeout` is just a example to reveal the relationship between Event Loop and promise. And I get the super answer I want exactly. Please not flag it as a duplicate

Comment: @PageYe Then vote to re-open and let the people decide.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Each event loop has a microtask queue and a macrotask queue.

A microtask is a task that is originally to be queued on the microtask queue rather than a task queue. Refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/webappapis.html#microtask-queue.

There are two kinds of microtasks:

- solitary callback microtasks, such as `Promise`，
- and compound microtasks, such as `Object.observe`, `MutationObserver` and `process.nextTick` in Node.js.

And the macrotask queue mainly contains `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `setImmediate`, `requestAnimationFrame`, `I/O` in Nodejs.

In a event Loop, these two task queues will run in two steps:

1. First, check whether there is a macrotask (call it X) in old macrotask queue ;
2. If X exists and it is running, wait for it to go to the next step until it was complete; otherwise, goto the next step immediately;
3. Second, run all microtasks of the microtask queue;
4. and when run the microtasks, we can still add some more microtaks into the queue, these tasks will also run.

In your example:

1. First, your Promise initialize `new Promise` and `resolve` are synchronous;
2. and then synchronously add a `setTimeout` macroTask into the macrotask queue;
3. then synchronously add the microtask `promise.then(function(){})` to the microtask queue, this task will run immediately, because the Promise initialize and resolve are synchronous, this task run before any macrotask; so, console.log the `p1 fulfilled`;
4. then add the second macrotask `setTimeout` to macrotask queue;
5. after this event loop ended, run the two macrotasks;

for this code:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("will be executed at the top of the next Event Loop")
}, 0)
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(1)
  }, 0)
});
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("will be executed at the bottom of the next Event Loop")
}, 0)
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  (function(j) {
    p1.then(function(value) {
      console.log("promise then - " + j)
    });
  })(i)
}
```

the output order:

```
will be executed at the top of the next Event Loop
promise then - 0
promise then - 1
promise then - 2
...
promise then - 99
will be executed at the bottom of the next Event Loop
```

1. First add three macrotask `setTimeout` to macrotask queue, and a microtask `promise.then()` to the microtask queue;
2. run a macrotask;
3. If condition true run all microtasks, but it's false, so go to the next step;
4. run the second macrotask;
5. check whether the promise resolved or not, the condition is true, then run all microtasks;
6. go on to run other macrotasks;

Comment: you say `X` will be checked first, however, is the `setTimeout` macroTask in step 2 the `X`? why not execute it first?

Comment: Because your promise initialize and resolve are synchronous, so when in step one, check whether there is a macrotask (called it X) in old macrotask queue, it will return false. Only after the synchronous code, the `setTimeout` macrotask will be invoked.

Comment: Since w3.org say nothing about the macrotask queue, what the difference between macrotask queue and task queue? Conceptually, does the microtask queue a kind of task queue or they are completely different?

Comment: "solitary callback microtasks, such as Promise" Would it be correct to be more specific here, instead stating: "solitary callback microtasks, which can only be created using Promise.prototype.then() or await"

Answer (score 3):

Promises will not be called unless the stack is clear of application code as per Dr. Axel Rauschmayer [here](http://2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html).

> ... the Promises/A+ specification demands
>   that the latter mode of execution be always used. It states so via the
>   following [requirement](http://promisesaplus.com/#point-34) (2.2.4) for the then() method:
>
> onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution
>   context stack contains only platform code.

It's important to note:

> That means that you code can rely on run-to-completion semantics (as
>   explained in part 1) and that chaining promises won’t starve other
>   tasks of processing time.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. In the OP's example, the `then` clause **was** called while there were pending `setTimeout` tasks, assuming those are considered "application code" or "platform code", which I don't know the definition of--what do they mean?