# EventLoop with async/await in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, event-loop

I try to understand how JS processes asynchronous methods and finally I have come to async/await. Trying to get a full insight, I have created this example:

```js
async function first() {
  console.log(9);
  await Promise.resolve(2).then((r) => console.log(r));
  console.log(0);
  await Promise.resolve(3).then((r) => console.log(r));
}

async function second() {
  console.log(10);
  await Promise.resolve(4).then((r) => console.log(r));
  console.log(11);
  await Promise.resolve(5).then((r) => console.log(r));
}
first();
second();
const promise = Promise.resolve("new Promise");
promise.then((str) => console.log(str));
```

```
//The output: 
//9
//10
//2
//4
//new Promise
//0
//11
//3
//5
```

So, I have a question, why does it have such an order, and how JS's EventLoop works with async/await

I tried to create some other examples with similar syntax but the result is the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relationship between event loop and Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375711/what-is-the-relationship-between-event-loop-and-promise)

Comment: I know how JS processes promises and other asynchronous methods, like setTimeout and setInterval, but it shows another answer, like await has a less priority in comparison with usual promises. Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&t=201s) is a fantastic talk about how the event loop works.

Comment: *I know how JS processes promises and other asynchronous methods, like setTimeout and setInterval* - promises use microtask queue and `setTimeout` and `setInterval` use event loop, they are different

Comment: `await Promise.resolve(2).then((r) => console.log(r));` -  You are making 3 things here: 1. Add `promise(2) to the queue. 2. When promise(2) resolves add another task `(r) => console.log(r)`. 3. When `(r) => console.log(r)` resolves add another task which will continue the function execution ( what `await` does)

Comment: Thus the counsel to never mix `await` and `then`...

Comment: Nothing to see here apart from "independent asynchronous methods execute interleaved in arbitrary order". Does it matter? What were you trying to understand here? Do you understand how it works if you had written the two methods using only promise chaining and without `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified time table of the most important evaluated expressions, the callstack at that time, the promise job queue (with promise reactions):

| Callstack | Evaluation | Job Queue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Script | `first()` | - |
| Script>first | `console.log(9)` | - |
| Script>first | `Promise.resolve(2).then()` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` |
| Script>first | `await <pending>` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` |
| Script | `second()` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` |
| Script>second | `console.log(10)` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` |
| Script>second | `Promise.resolve(4).then()` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` `(r=4)=>console.log(r)` |
| Script>second | `await <pending>` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` `(r=4)=>console.log(r)` |
| Script | `promise = Promise.resolve("new Promise")` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` `(r=4)=>console.log(r)` |
| Script | `promise.then((str)=>console.log(str))` | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` `(r=4)=>console.log(r)` `(str="new Promise")=> console.log(str)` |
| Job | `(r=2)=>console.log(r)` | `(r=4)=>console.log(r)` `(str="new Promise")=> console.log(str)` |
| Job>anonym | `console.log(2)` | `(r=4)=>console.log(r)` `(str="new Promise")=> console.log(str)` `resume first()` |
| Job | `(r=4)=>console.log(r)` | `(str="new Promise")=> console.log(str)` `resume first()` |
| Job>anonym | `console.log(4)` | `(str="new Promise")=> console.log(str)` `resume first()` `resume second()` |
| Job | `(str="new Promise")=> console.log(str)` | `resume first()` `resume second()` |
| Job>anonym | `console.log("new Promise")` | `resume first()` `resume second()` |
| Job | `resume first()` | `resume second()` |
| Job>first | `console.log(0)` | `resume second()` |
| Job>first | `Promise.resolve(3).then()` | `resume second()` `(r=3)=>console.log(r)` |
| Job>first | `await <pending>` | `resume second()` `(r=3)=>console.log(r)` |
| Job | `resume second()` | `(r=3)=>console.log(r)` |
| Job>second | `console.log(11)` | `(r=3)=>console.log(r)` |
| Job>second | `Promise.resolve(5).then()` | `(r=0)=>console.log(r)` `(r=5)=>console.log(r)` |
| Job>second | `await <pending>` | `(r=3)=>console.log(r)` `(r=5)=>console.log(r)` |
| Job | `(r=3)=>console.log(r)` | `(r=5)=>console.log(r)` |
| Job>anonym | `console.log(3)` | `(r=5)=>console.log(r)` `resume first()` |
| Job | `(r=5)=>console.log(r)` | `resume first()` |
| Job>anonym | `console.log(5)` | `resume first()` `resume second()` |
| Job | `resum first()` | `resume second()` |
| Job>first | - | `resume second()` |
| Job | `resume second()` | - |
| Job>second | - | - |

Some points to highlight:

- When a `then` method is executed on a promise that is in a fulfilled state,  a job is added to a job queue. When the script has been executed to completion the first job in the promise job queue is extracted and executed.
- Be aware that when a `then` method is executed this creates a new promise that is pending, even when `then` is called on a resolved promise. That pending promise will only resolve when the callback passed as argument has been executed, and this happens via a job (so, asynchronously).
- After the expression following an `await` is executed, the `async` function's running state is saved, and the function **returns**. This running state will be restored by a job that is queued when the awaited promise resolves.

Hope this clarifies a few things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

This is:

```
async function first() {
  console.log(9);
  await Promise.resolve(2).then((r) => console.log(r));
  console.log(0);
  await Promise.resolve(3).then((r) => console.log(r));
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
function first() {
  console.log(9);
  return Promise.resolve(2).then((r) => console.log(r)).then(() => {
    console.log(0);
    return Promise.resolve(3).then((r) => console.log(r));
  });
}
```

```js
function first() {
  console.log(9);
  return Promise.resolve(2).then((r) => console.log(r)).then(() => {
    console.log(0);
    return Promise.resolve(3).then((r) => console.log(r));
  })
}

function second() {
  console.log(10);
  return Promise.resolve(4).then((r) => console.log(r)).then(() => {
    console.log(11);
    Promise.resolve(5).then((r) => console.log(r));
  })
}
first();
second();
const promise = Promise.resolve("new Promise");
promise.then((str) => console.log(str));
```

Same with better numbering

```js
function first() {
  console.log(1);
  return Promise.resolve('a').then((r) => console.log(4, r)).then(() => {
    console.log(7);
    return Promise.resolve('b').then((r) => console.log(9, r));
  })
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
  return Promise.resolve('c').then((r) => console.log(5, r)).then(() => {
    console.log(8);
    Promise.resolve('d').then((r) => console.log(10, r));
  })
}
first();
second();
console.log(3)
const promise = Promise.resolve('e');
promise.then((str) => console.log(6, str));
```